# Why Android crash when NEON SIMDization enabled? signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, simd, neon

I am in the process of doing some NEON based SIMDization to my code.
It works perfectly fine with out SIMDization, but adding the following one line in the makefile causes it to crash,

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
endif
```

Can someone please help to identify why it crashes just by enabling NEON with the code remaining absolutely same?

Regards,
Subhransu

Comment: Is it possible that you run it on a device without NEON support? You don't share anything about your code so it can be many things at this point.

Comment: You got it solved? I am also now running into same issue!

Answer (score 0):

First check your processor features, to see if it actually have NEON,

> NOT ALL ARMv7-BASED ANDROID DEVICES WILL SUPPORT NEON

you can look up the processor data sheet.

It is maybe your source code, according to documents,

> When listing sources files in your LOCAL_SRC_FILES variable, you now
>   have the option of using the .neon suffix to indicate that you want to
>   corresponding source(s) to be built with Neon support. For example:
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c.neon bar.c
>
> Will only build 'foo.c' with NEON support.

for build, are you targeting armeabi-v7a ABI ? you can check it in your Android.mk
by

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
```

So check all these factors, see what's causing the crash

The NDK example is a good source for starting, have a look at it.
Good luck